# Verify X509 cert signature with DSA public key

Tags: linux, openssl, x509, verify, dsa

I need to verify a X509 cert signature with a DSA public key. My cert file is x509.crt and my DSA public key is in a file named dsa_pub.key

I am trying to use openssl for this purpose. I have read the openssl verify documentation but I cant find any reference to DSA within it.

When I run the following command, I can see my DSA Public Key within the cert:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text -noout
```

However, I am hitting a wall when it comes to verifying cert.crt using my DSA public key from the file dsa_pub.key

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/220508

Answer (score 0):

To verify, use the command pkeyutl as well as the verify command. See the documentation [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/pkeyutl.html) for details.